# Rails reputation system for a content management system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ranking

I am working on CMS and I need to implement a reputation system which enable these features

1. Badges
2. Points
3. Ranks

I found this gem from twitter, [activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) but I'm not pretty sure how to use this on my own application. Appreciate if someone can help me out. Here is my scenario. (Example only)

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :jobs
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
# has a name and points field 
# example: Cat A, 5 
# example: Cat B, 10
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :employee
belongs_to :category
end
```

So the models are `Managers, Employees, Jobs, Categories.` Basically `Manager` create `Job` entries and assign `Employee` and `Category` for each Job entry.

What I need to do is, everytime when Manager create a Job entry, assign points to Employee based on the Job Category they belongs to, and calculate Rank or assign badge as per the points they have earned. (Using `Category.points)`

Is this doable from above Gem? if so, how do I use `has_reputation` in my models.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) does not include badges.

One popular gem that meets your requirements (badges, points and rankings) is [merit](https://github.com/tute/merit).

Answer (score 1):

Check out R. Bates railscast on this gem...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system

..that should get you moving the right direction.

Comment: Thanks - I saw this one, but all these examples are for, `User` model involves for up/down voting. In my case a Manager model create the job entries and I should assign the points on this level.

Comment: Many you could use the same logic that is involved in the User model, just apply it to Manager, Employee, etc. Rather than assigning the points to an up/down vote, you just hard code the logic based on whatever trigger you want.

Comment: I added this to `Category` model `has_reputation :category_points, :source => :employee` and inside the Job model I have this `after_save` method   `self.category.increase_evaluation(:category_points, self.category.score.to_i, self.employee)` - But not sure what would come under `Employee` model yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my clone of [Paths of Glory](https://github.com/nazar/paths_of_glory), a plugin to manage user achievements/badges.

An example page generated by this plugin can be seen [here](http://recipetrees.com/profiles/1_nazar-aziz) (click on the Badges tab.)

There are several other forks of this plugin and is worth exploring the clone tree.

HTH and good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems out dated. I still need to try this with activerecord-reputation-system gem.